# Count the number of complex, real and pure imaginary numbers in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, python-cmath

Given a Numpy array/matrix, what is pythonic way to count the number of complex, pure real and pure imaginary number:

```
[[ 1.   +0.j     1.   +0.j     1.   +0.j     1.   +0.j     1.   +0.j   ]
 [ 1.   +0.j     0.309+0.951j -0.809+0.588j -0.809-0.588j  0.309-0.951j]
 [ 1.   +0.j    -0.809+0.588j  0.309-0.951j  0.309+0.951j -0.809-0.588j]
 [ 1.   +0.j    -0.809-0.588j  0.309+0.951j  0.309-0.951j -0.809+0.588j]
 [ 1.   +0.j     0.309-0.951j -0.809-0.588j -0.809+0.588j  0.309+0.951j]]
```

Note: Please ignore the fact that complex numbers are superset of Imaginary and Real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> complex

A number is complex if and only if its imaginary part is not zero, and its real part is not zero. Therefore:

```py
np.count_nonzero(
    np.logical_and(
        np.logical_not(
            np.equal(x.imag, 0)
        ),
        np.logical_not(
            np.equal(x.real, 0)
        )
    )
)
```

> pure real

Use [`numpy.isreal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html).

```py
np.count_nonzero(np.isreal(x))
```

> pure imaginary number

A number is pure imaginary if and only if:

- its imaginary part is not zero, and
- its real part *is* zero.

Therefore:

```py
np.count_nonzero(
    np.logical_and(
        np.logical_not(
            np.equal(x.imag, 0)
        ),
        np.equal(x.real, 0)
    )
)
```